# workflow parallel is executed in the same time as without parallel

Tags: powershell

I've tried searching in text in parallel and no. Runtime is the same
To determine the execution time, I used a Measure-Command -Expression

```
$listlogtoday = Get-ChildItem -Path $folder\*.log | Where-Object Length -ne 0
$arraylist = $listlogtoday.Name
$tmp="code "


workflow Test-ParallelForeach 
{
  param(
    [array[]]$arraylist 
  )

  foreach -parallel ($namefile in $arraylist )
{
 $text = ((Select-String -Path "C:\test_ps1\$namefile" -Pattern "text_text") -replace "(?s)^.*$tmp", '') -replace "text2_text2.",""
 $allkey += $text
}

}

Test-ParallelForeach -arraylist $arraylist

$allkey = $allkey | select -Unique
write-host ($allkey -join "`n")
```

Comment: Maybe [`ForEach -Parallel …`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psworkflow/about/about_foreach-parallel)? BTW, where is defined `$allkey` in your script? Moreover, note that `+=` operation could be _very_ time consuming.

Comment: I don't see a [`parallel { }`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/system-center/sma/overview-powershell-workflows?view=sc-sma-2019#Parallel) block in your code. Not sure what you're trying to test.

Comment: sorry, forget add -parallel. Result the same )

Comment: param(
    [array[]]$arraylist

Comment: Are you looking for multi threading on PowerShell ? Workflow is not the best way you can achieve that